# Determine if a sibling node with text exists

Tags: xml, xpath, find, selector

I want to determine if a node contains the string `abc` using `following-sibling`.

So far I'm looping through each `item` node and I want to determine if that `item` contains a `node` with the string `abc`

This is what i've tried so far:

```
contains(node/following-sibling::node[text()], 'abc')
```

XML:

```
<doc>
<item>
<node>1abc2</node>
<node>4</node>
<node>x</node>
</item>
<item>
<node>1</node>
<node>2abcX</node>
<node>x</node>
</item>
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is *"determine if that `item` contains a `node` with the string `abc`"* then you don't need `following-sibling`. Use this to select all such nodes:

```
node[contains(., 'abc')]
```

This matches a `node` in both `item` elements provided.

If you want to check for a child `node` having a following sibling `node` with that text, then use:

```
node[following-sibling::node[contains(., 'abc')]]
```

This only matches the first `node` in the second `item`.

Either of these can be explicity converted to a boolean with the [`boolean` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean). For example:

```
boolean(node[following-sibling::node[contains(., 'abc')]])
```

This returns true if at least one node is selected by the expression (i.e. the node-set is non-empty).

Answer (score 0):

This XSL produces a single node, there's only 1 "node" that has a "node" following it with the string "abc".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 

<xsl:template match="/">
<doc>
    <xsl:for-each select='/doc/item/node[following-sibling::node[contains(.,"abc")]]'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</doc>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```